# create a link for a post which leads a user to view the full post

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm showing the posts from a blog to the user and those posts are truncated with the '...'(three dots) I want to make these '...' as link and when someone click on that link , it should shows the full post

I'm truncating the post with following line of code.

```
{{ strlen($post->body) > 50 ? "...": "" }}
```

how can I make a hyper link from these '...' in the above line of code to view particular post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround them with an `<a>` tag for example:

```
<a href="{{ route('route_of_the_post') }}">{{ strlen($post->body) > 50 ? "...": "" }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`str_limit`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-str-limit) helper function does what you're doing for you.

```
{!! str_limit(e($post->body), 50, "<a href='{route('post.show', $post)}'>...</a>") !!}
```

Here's each parameter of the function explained:

1. `e($post->body)` -- The post body, with HTML escaped
2. `50` -- The maximum length of the string
3. `"<a href='{route('post.show', $post)}'>...</a>"` -- The text to go in place of the '...'. In this case we make it a link to go to the post
   Replace `route('post.show', $post)` with whatever code you have to link to a post.